# I want to check the storage used by GKE Node

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created a GKE cluster with 20 GB of storage and it is runnning 4 pods. 3 of them are angular application and 1 is node applicaiton and 10.5GB is already used and only 3.96 GB is left. I wanted to check how much storage is used by whom these 4 pods cannot use that much of storage i think. Is there any way to check how and who is using the storage

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaNfw.png)

No ephemeral-storage is being used

[Screenshot of ephemeral-storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lPth.png)